# what is the way to communicate with neo4j server for web application

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to make a web app with neo4j. But the problem is, everywhere the tutorials are for neo4j in embedded mode which is not suitable for web app( please correct me if i am wrong). I found [this](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc) to connect to neo4j server but the maven dependency is not working. There is a downloadable jar file at that link, i added it to my library and tried with example code but the it showing `classnotfoundexception`. I went to maven repository site to search that neo4j-jdbc but cann't find anything . It seems i am stuck at the very first thing . Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "`neo4j in embedded mode which is not suitable for web app`". I am able to use my Asp.Net Website connect to the Neo4J rest api's without any issues. anything specific you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today the best way to interact with Neo4j is the [transactional Cypher REST endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html). Depending on your client side language/framework couple of drivers do exists, see http://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/.

The current JDBC does have dependencies on jar files that are not available via maven central and consequently cannot be sent to maven central either. https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc shows an example how to use it.

Comment: did you used this jdbc driver, i am trying to use it , can not fetch data from database but without any error, the query is perfectly working in database console. I just copied it from the example.

Comment: I assume your Neo4j instance requires authentication and you don't provide it in JDBC.

Comment: may be...ok no problem...thanks...i just implemented by rest api.